# flask endpoint which is defined returns 404

Tags: python, http, flask, backend

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.users = {}
app.id_count = 1


@app.route("/ping", methods = ['GET'])
def ping():
        return "pong"



@app.route("/sign-up",methods = ['POST'])
def sign_up():
        new_user = request.json
        new_user["id"] = app.id_count
        app.users[app.id_count]= new_user
        app.id_count = app.id_count +1

        return jsonify(new_user)


if __name__ =='__main__':
        app.run()
```

I tried to send a HTTP request to endpoint /sign-up which is defined as above,

`127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2021 22:02:02] "POST /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

It seems like a really simple problem and I don't see it.

Comment: the ping pong endpoint still works fine.

Comment: Try running your function through a debugger

Answer (score 0):

I was running these on WSL2 ubuntu. (both server and client)

and I eventually tried running this on my Windows Pycharm which is not a virtual machine, and it worked fine.

I wonder why /ping works fine tho, will be finishing this course on ordinary windows from now on for sure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).